# Stats test which test of the NULL that a distribution is uniformally distributed

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, uniform-distribution

I'm looking for a statistical test which tells the probability that a given sample comes from a uniform distribution.

Shapiro test wether a sample comes from a normal distribution. I'm looking a similar test which test wether a sample comes from a uniform distribution.

Thank you

Comment: NB Non-Bayesian tests can't give you the probability that a sample comes from a uniformly distributed population; only the probability that *if* it does you'd get a test statistic as or more extreme than the one you got.

Comment: @Scortchi Thank you for your comment. Although I'm not really understanding it. So you mean that by running a K-S test on my sample data I will know wether my sample is uniformly distributed but not wether it comes from a uniformly distributed popn ?

Comment: That's not what I meant. It was a general warning about [misinterpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value#Misunderstandings) of p-values - they are not the probability that the null hypothesis is true.

Comment: @Scortchi AAhh ok. Yes you're absolutely right. I should be more accurate in my question. I guess I did a common mistake. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for a statistical test which tells the probability that a given sample comes from a uniform distribution.

No frequentist test will tell you that probability.

> Shapiro test wether a sample comes from a normal distribution. I'm looking a similar test which test wether a sample comes from a uniform distribution.

Do you mean continuous or discrete uniformity?

Is this a fully specified uniform, or one where the lower and upper limits aren't known (must be estimated)?

There are several suitable tests for fully specified continuous uniformity, including *Kolmogorov-Smirnov*, *Cramer-von Mises* and *Anderson-Darling*. There's also the *Neyman-Barton-type Smooth tests* (e.g. see Rayner and Best's books and articles on smooth tests). There are other such tests. If you know likely/interesting alternatives, that helps in the choice of test.

If you like the Shapiro-Wilk, it's possible to construct a similar kind of test for uniformity with unspecified bounds.

Alternatively, at the cost of two data points, you can exploit the properties of the uniform distribution to turn the previous fully-specified tests into tests where the bounds on the uniform are unspecified:

If $a=X_{(1)}$ and $b=X_{(n)}$ are the smallest and largest observations, just calculate $U_i = \frac{X_i - a}{b-a}$ for all the observations except you throw out the smallest and largest and test against fully-specified-uniformity on the remaining $n-2$ data values.

Comment: It is a continuous variable. I'd like actually to be able to specified by myself the boundaries. For example I have these values (0.12,0.65,0.23,0.97,0.74,0.19,0.48) and I want to ask wether these values seem to be drawn from a uniform distribution with boundaries at 0.08 and 1 (numbers that I chose and which are outside from the range of observed values.) Could I use 0.08 and 1 in place of your a and b ? What should I do then with all these Ui ? Should a add them and divide the total by the number of observation ?! Do I get a p.value ? Does it correspond to a two-sided thing ? Thanks!

Comment: If you're choosing those based on having seen the data, you can't calculate the distribution of the test statistic given the data. If those are chosen *a priori*, there's no problem. I'd suggest separating the issue of testing uniformity and the inference relating to your choice of endpoints into two stages. ... "*What should I do then with all these Ui*" -- you choose and then perform a goodness of fit test on them.

Comment: Sure those endpoints are set before seing the data. So do I get a p.value by doing: "sum for all i of (xi-a)/(b-a) and divide the total by the number of i" ? I expect to have a bias from this distribution on one side only. Can I have a p.value for a one-sided test ?

Comment: hum... perform a goodness of fit test. Like a K-S test ?

Comment: Yes, or one of the others

Answer (score 1):

You could try a [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) of your data against a uniform distribution.